# Aggregation in function not working right

Tags: python, aggregate-functions

Hello so I have a python function that's working but not in the way I expect and I'm not sure where my code is off.

```
def preprocess(text):
    case = truecase.get_true_case(text)
    doc = nlp(case)
    return doc

def summarize_texts(texts):
    actions = {}
    entities = {}
    for item in texts:
        doc = preprocess(item)
        for token in doc:
            if token.pos_ == "VERB":
                actions[str.lower(token.text)] = actions.get(token.text, 0) +1
        for token in doc.ents:
            entities[token.label_] = [token.text]
            if token.text not in entities[token.label_]:
                entities[token.label_].append(token.text)
    return {
        'actions': actions,
        'entities': entities
    }
```

when I call the function for a list of sentences, this is the output I get:

```
docs = [
    "Play something by Billie Holiday, and play again",
    "Set a timer for five minutes",
    "Play it again, Sam"
]

summarize_texts(docs)

output: {'actions': {'play': 1, 'set': 1},
 'entities': {'PERSON': ['Sam'], 'TIME': ['five minutes']}}
```

It it's working in that it's finding the action keys and entities keys but I am having two issues.

1. it's not counting the actions right
2. it's only storing the last value of each entity.

output should be:

```
output: {'actions': {'play': 3, 'set': 1},
 'entities': {'PERSON': ['Billie','Sam'], 'TIME': ['five minutes']}}
```

Any help would be AMAZING! I have a feeling its something easy but just too brain fried to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing the data structures, not simply updating the values. You only want to create a new container if does not exist at that point.

For actions:

```
if token.pos_ == "VERB":
    action_key = str.lower(token.text)

    if action_key not in actions:
        actions[action_key] = 0

    actions[action_key] += 1
```

For entities:

```
for token in doc.ents:
    entity_key = token.label_
    entity_value = token.text

    if entity_key not in entities:
        entities[entity_key] = []

    if entity_value not in entities[entity_key]:
        entities[entity_key].append(entity_value)
```

As a note, you can simplify this logic by using a `defaultdict`. You can also use a set rather than checking the list for duplicates each time

```
actions = defaultdict(int)
entities = defaultdict(set)
...

if token.pos_ == "VERB":
    actions[str.lower(token.text)] += 1
...

for token in doc.ents:
    entities[token.label_].add(token.text)
```

Comment: Thank you @flakes ! the only issue is that the output is wrong. I believe the return is on the wrong level. ``` output: {'actions': {'play': 14, 'set': 6},
 'entities': {'PERSON': ['Billie holiday', 'Sam'], 'TIME': ['five minutes']}}" It's over counting the plays and set should be 'play' : 3, 'set' : 1

Answer (score 0):

You're not consistent in converting the token to lowercase. You use the lowercase version when assigning to the dictionary, but the original case when calling `actions.get()`. So if the token has mixed case, you'll keep on getting the default when you call `actions.get()`, and keep setting it to 1.

```
actions[token.text.lower()] = actions.get(token.text.lower(), 0) +1
```